# How to use virtualmin to manage an existing website?

Tags: apache2, php

I installed virtualmin on Ubuntu14.04 that was already hosting a website. Now when I log into virtuamin, I don't see any virtual server, and my previous working website now shows PHP code instead of executing it. I don't know much technical detail about linux hosting, for all of my sites, I use webmin/virtualmin to manage. So at this point, I don't know how I can bring the website back and put in under virtualmin's control.

The website was set up by someone else, its files are still under /home/admin/myweb.site/, and the mysql database is intact also. I could just create a new virtual server in virtualmin, and then move the files to the new virtual server and export/import the database. But for learning purpose, I'd like to know if there is anyway to integrate the existing website into virtualmin so I can manage it without having to go through the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

You were given your answer here https://www.virtualmin.com/node/54366

> Right at the top of the download page it says you need to install your
>   operating system from scratch and then install Virtualmin. As far as I
>   know, **there is not a way to put Virtualmin on top of an existing web
>   server with active sites**.

You could open a ticket

First, make sure you are using a supported OS - https://www.virtualmin.com/os-support.html

> **non-LTS releases are not supported**

Tickets here - https://www.virtualmin.com/project/issues